# How to expense $(a+b)^\alpha$ into multinomial with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

As we all know, the binomial expension is as follows
$$
(a+b)^2 = a^2 +2ab +b^2.
$$
When the power number is a real number, not a integral, how to expense $(a+b)^\alpha$ into multinomial with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: See [Binomial Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tetori's reference ([Newton's binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)) is what you want.  And note: for a case $(a+b)^\alpha$, say $|a|>|b|$, write
$$
(a+b)^\alpha = a^\alpha \left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)^\alpha
$$
and use the series on the second factor.  The case $|a|=|b|$ is more complicated.  (See "conditions of convergence" on that page.)